# How to setup the same scale for X axis (timestamp) in multiple graphs using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I am using `Python` and `Matplotlib` to try to generate the following: four charts plotting the amount of messages received in a system VS the delay in processing these messages, in a given period of time, in intervals of 5 minutes.

That is, the **`X`** axis shows time from moment **`A`** to moment **`B`** (in the format "`%Y-%m-%d %H:%M`") in intervals of five minutes, while the left **`Y`** axis shows the amount of messages received at any given moment, and the right **`Y`** axis shows the delays in processing these messages.

Now, I got to plotting both `X` axes in the chart, but I need the timestamps to be the same for every graph, that is, all must start and end at the same point in time, even if there are no events in those times for some of the charts (e.g., chart#1 starts at 15:50 of the 10/5/2015 and stopped at 14:00 11/5/2015, even if in one of them the events start happening at 17:00 of 10/5). And that's the killer.

Does anyone know how can I do this? Thanks a lot

Comment: Please provide the code you have so far. Ideally make it a reproducible example we can run, without having to read external data first.

Comment: You may want to **read whathaveyoutried.com & show some respect** to the StackOverflow Community, which strongly encourages to post high quality questions, altogether with a **MCVE ( a Minimum-Complete-Verifiable-Example of code ) showing what-you-have-tried so far**. You may want to update your post, so as to meet this minimum reasonable level of quality & to show your will to respect other StackOverflow contributing members. They are professionals who love to answer good questions on MCVE-related issues. **Enjoy being StackOverflow Contributing Member & do support this Community Netiquette**

Comment: Set the same **`.set_xlim( x_min, x_MAX )`** as answered below on all graphs to get them be the same on all graphs.

Answer (score -1):

> Does anyone know how can I do this?

Yes.

---

If Stack Overflow would allow for non-MCVE posts in Questions, the simplistic Answers, saying just "Yes", would spring off the box, but would bring no real experience to the great Community the StackOverflow undoubtedly is.

---

Think about it for a while & you get the point. This would be definitely a way no one would appreciate.

---

Q: How...?

You may re-use some of the formatting tricks. You might have already experienced, that `matplotlib`'s complex structure is sort-of sensitive, where the formatting takes place in the `Figure` processing. So some things work "before" plotting data, some only "after" plotting data-points/lines. So do not hesitate to test/reorder sections so as to get the Look & Feel you wish to have within a reasonable time spent on these polishing touches ( the real-value is typically in the data-related insights & phenomena-related experience converted to some new, strategic value called knowlege, isn't it? ).

So a few cents:

```
#---------------------------------------------------- # X-AXIS FORMATTING         
aPlotAX.set_xlim( x_min, x_MAX )                      # X-AXIS LIMITs ---    

#lt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(      matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator( secs ) )
#lt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(    matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter( lambda pos, _: time.strftime( "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime( pos ) ) ) )

aPlotAX.xaxis.set_major_locator(   AutoDateLocator() )
aPlotAX.xaxis.set_minor_locator(       HourLocator() )
#PlotAX.xaxis.set_minor_locator(     MinuteLocator() ) # if not too dense

aPlotAX.xaxis.set_major_formatter( DateFormatter( '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' ) )

# -------------------------------------------------------------------- X-FORMAT
#----------------------------------------------- # 90-deg x-tick-LABELs
try:
    plt.setp( plt.gca().get_xticklabels(),  rotation            = 90,
                                            horizontalalignment = 'right'
                                            )
except:
    print "DEBUG: EXC() on plt.setp( plt.gca().get_xticklabels(),  rotation = 90, ... )"

# --------------------------------------------- # "tight"-en LAYOUT 
try:
    plt.tight_layout()
except:
    print "DEBUG: EXC() on plt.tight_layout()"
'''
SOME pre-SAVE_AS-configuration(s) |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

#Fig.set_figwidth(  1600.0 )
#Fig.set_figheight( 1400.0 )
#                   facecolor = 'k',                  # for inverse colourscheme
#                   edgecolor = 'w',
aFig = plt.figure(  figsize   = ( 5, 5 ), dpi = 100 ) # size not in [inch], but in [spatial-units] a 100-px-each...

#lt .savefig( <aFileNAME.PNG>, transparent = True, dpi = 300 )                      # .PNG with alpha-channel background                        std-[px]-size are 800x600 at dpi

#lt .savefig( <aFileNAME.SVG>, transparent = True, dpi = 300 )                      # .SVG with alpha-channel background                        std-[px]-size are 800x600 at dpi
#lt .savefig( <aFileNAME.000>, transparent = True, dpi = 300, format = "svg" )      # .SVG with alpha-channel background                        std-[px]-size are 800x600 at dpi

#lt .savefig( <aFileNAME.PDF>, transparent = True, dpi = 300 )                      # .PDF with alpha-channel background                        std-[px]-size are 800x600 at dpi

# from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages                              # .PDF-multi-page document
# pdf_pages = PdfPages('barcharts.pdf')
# aFig = plt.Figure...
# plt.plot...
# pdf_pages.savefig( aFig )     # .closes aPdfPAGE
# ...plot
# pdf_pages.savefig( aFig )     # .closes aPdfPAGE
# pdf_pages.close()             # Finally: fileIO on disk
```